# What is the different between static method and exported new instance of class

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, static, instance

Having this 2 code snippets. what is the difference between them and in what case you prefer one on another?

```
export default class A {
    static methodA() {
        console.log('Method A');
    }
}
```

with the following usage:

```
import A from 'a';

function test() {
    A.methodA()
}
```

VS this 2nd snippet:

```
class A {
    methodA() {
        console.log('Method A');
    }
}

export default new A();
```

with the following usage:

```
import A from 'a';//I know that semantically I should have import a - but for the sake of this question I wrote import A.

function test() {
    A.methodA();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not much really. Even a `class` is an object, so in one case you have an object which has a property `methodA` which is a function, and in the other case you have an object which has a property `methodA` which is a function.

The only difference is that you can do `new A` when `A` is a class, but you can't when it's already an instance.

Answer (score 1):

The second case is what's known as the *singleton pattern*, wherein you define a class that will only ever have one instance. Which one you prefer depends mostly on your use case and personal taste. If you're interested in more details I'd recommend you read up on singletons, and design patterns in general.

Comment: Hi @Mate - thanks, I know it's a singleton and the meaning of singleton. I was wondering if under the hood there is a difference between those two method. Cause of in first example all methods and properties are static than - it behaves the same as singleton class.

Comment: In the first example, you can instantiate `A`. In the second, you can't. That's pretty much it.